# How to sort a linked list (of F1 drivers) by points and positions?

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

```
struct element_struct {
    char name[MAX];
    char team[MAX];
    int points;
    int positions[NRACES];
};
```

this is the driver, and I have already created everything to add them to the list.
Now the tricky part is to actually sort them not only by the points, but if 2 or more were to have the same score.

clarifications here:

the *position* is added by the user when creating a new driver or when the user has to insert the result of another race.

It's an array because there are multiple races and the array contains all the finishing positions of a driver, so each cell of the array contains the finishing positions of a driver in a certain race of the F1 calendar and *has to be used only to decide the order of 2+ drivers with the same amount of *points**.

The decision should compare each position and the one who has finished higher on the grid should be placed before the others.

Please tell me if there is more that's unclear.

Comment: You are talking about a driver's position but you have an array of positions for each driver. How is that supposed to be handled? Take the sum? Pick best position? Something else?

Comment: @Gerhardh I suppose the positions array contains the driver's position for each of the past races.

Comment: F1 Rules are this: *The winner of the annual Driver's Championship is the 
           driver with the most points. The same hold true for the 
           Constructors' Championship. If two or more drivers (or 
           constructors) have the same number of points, a tie 
           breaker system is used. The one with the most wins is 
           ranked higher. If the number of wins are the same, it goes 
           to the one with the most second places and so on*

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes, that is what I assume. But still it has to be defined how the position is handled. Update: The rules cites by selbie seem to be a good start.

Comment: Please [edit] and tell us exactly how `positions` is supposed to be handled, possibly by showing an example.

Comment: I think the ambiguity is knowing if a race winner is "position 0" or is that "position 1". Another ambiguity is the number of possible race positions. F1 typically has 20 drivers per race (hence P1 - P20). But that number can change over the years.

Comment: I'm also assuming that `positions` is an array of each driver's finishes *per race* and not *the count of finishes at a position*.

Comment: @selbie I want to use the array to store the 20+ results of  the races, so in the first cell of the array I want to store the finishing position of a certain driver in the first race, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got an array of drivers. In this example, 20 drivers.

```
const size_t N = 20;
struct element_struct racers[N] = {... you've filled this in ... }
```

Then you can use [qsort](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) to sort them in descending point order using a comparison function:

```
int CompareDrivers(const void* d1, const void* d2)
{
    const element_struct* driver1 = (const element_struct*)d1;
    const element_struct* driver2 = (const element_struct*)d2;

    // sort descending in points
    // hence if driver1 has more points, he's "less than" driver2 in sort order.

    if (driver1->points > driver2->points)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (driver1->points < driver2->points)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // tie breaker according to F1 rules:
    /*
       The winner of the annual Driver's Championship is the 
       driver with the most points. The same hold true for the 
       Constructors' Championship. If two or more drivers (or 
       constructors) have the same number of points, a tie 
       breaker system is used. The one with the most wins is 
       ranked higher. If the number of wins are the same, it goes 
       to the one with the most second places and so on
    */

    // Assume positions are numbered 1-20 and position 21 is
    // the "did not finish designation".

    const int d1_positions[MAX_POSITIONS+2]={0};
    const int d1_positions[MAX_POSITIONS+2]={0};

    for (int i = 0; i < NRACES; i++)
    {
        int d1Position = driver1->positions[i];
        d1_positions[d1Position]++;

        int d2Position = driver2->positions[i];
        d1_positions[d2Position]++;
    }

    for (int j = 1; i <= MAX_POSITIONS; i++)
    {
        if (d1_positions[j] > d1_positions[j])
        {
           return -1;
        }
        if (d1_positions[j] < d1_positions[j])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the corresponding qsort:

```
qsort(racers, N, sizeof(element_struct), CompareDrivers);
```

When qsort returns, the drivers will be in descending order in terms of points.

Comment: Unluckily I have a linked list, although I appreciate this other method, since I have already completed doing the same task with arrays

Comment: @Poinsaett allocate a temporary array of pointers to the data and sort it; this will likely be faster in the long-run then [sorting linked-lists](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/lib/list_sort.c.html), (but not stable; doesn't matter here.)

Comment: @Neil ok, very interesting, thanks